# Remove the delimiters in column value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have value in snowlflake

```
"<p>jeep is back under the tree</p>"
```

The column is variant datatype in table.

How do i get only **jeep is back under the tree**, Any suggestion please.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regexp_replace function to strip most HTML tags:

```
with T1 as
(
    select '<p>jeep is back under the tree</p>'::variant as V
)
select regexp_replace(V, '<[^>]*>', '') as HTML_TAGS_STRIPPED from T1
;
```

Output:

| HTML_TAGS_STRIPPED |
| --- |
| jeep is back under the tree |